# VBA Data Validation from another worksheet

Tags: vba, charts

I currently have 2 worksheets. Sheet1 and Sheet3. In Sheet3, I have multiple publicly traded companies going across the first row. Under each company, I have a chart/graph name that I was able to find through another workbook that is relevant to the company.

In sheet1, I have a column of the companies and a column for graph. I want to create a drop down list that will allow a user to select a graph and open it in a PDF or expanded version. How would I go about doing this?

```
Sub appendGraphs()
Dim source, target As Worksheet
Dim LC, RC As Integer
Set source = Sheet5
Set target = Sheet1
LC = source.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For i = 2 To LC ' collect strings from each column and store it to tempList to feed to datavalidation

    RC = source.Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
    ReDim tempList(1 To RC) As String
    For n = 2 To UBound(tempList)
        tempList(n) = source.Cells(i, n).Value
    With target.Cells(findRowB(source.Cells(1, i).Value, Sheet1), 10).Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
        Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=tempList
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True

    End With

    Next

Next
```

End Sub

```
Function findRowB(x As String, Optional y As Worksheet) As Integer 'finds specific row to start writing values in
Dim expectedRow As Range
Dim wbsheet As Worksheet
If y Is Nothing Then
    Set wbsheet = ActiveSheet
Else
    Set wbsheet = y
End If
Set expectedRow = wbsheet.Range("C:C").Find(What:=x, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
findRowB = expectedRow.Row
```

End Function

Comment: In your "Developer" ribbon you press "Record Macro" and accept the settings in the dialog. Then you do manually the operations that lead you to the result. Then you press "Stop Recording", and you look into the newly created script to see how is done. Then you adapt the code to your needs, and you make it generic (i.e. not only for the particular case that you performed manually).

Answer (score 0):

No one will do all that vba for you. Just Google each part individually, here I will get you started.

Create a drop down,
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-dropdown-list-7693307a-59ef-400a-b769-c5402dce407b

Link it,
http://software-solutions-online.com/2014/02/21/excel-vba-drop-down-lists/

Save it as a pdf,
http://www.contextures.com/excelvbapdf.html

Google is your friend!

Or use record a macro.

Feel free to ask questions.

Comment: Hmm I went with the record macro option and I seem to have a pretty good idea. One quick question is, how do I loop through the columns and present a dynamic range of the values to feed into the validation?

Comment: I was able to find the value of the last row but how do I assign a range to it? Range(firstrow, lastrow).select?

Comment: Not understanding the last question. You want the range of values? From the first row to the last row? Just grab the row number of the last row, for(i = 0; i < row; i++){ thiscell = Cell('A',i).value } then you can do whatever you want with what is in the cell.

Comment: Yes but how do I select the range of it? I grabbed the row number of the last value but I want to select everything in the column from the 2nd row to the row number of the last value to feed into the data validation formula.

Comment: That's a bad way to do it. You'll be dealing with ranges at that point and it can get messy when you are playing with ranges and cell values. Just loop through each item and store it in an array. http://www.homeandlearn.org/arrays_and_loops.html

Comment: Hmm after I store it in an array, I should be able to feed it into a data validation right?

Comment: Yup, once you have your array of data, just loop through it to get it out and feed it to your data validation. Also, recording macros can get messy, I recommend doing most of it on your own and just using snippets from the record. It will make it easier to read later and help you understand it now.

Comment: Please chose my answer for the help!

Comment: Of course! Let me finish the part I want to finish the project before I close the thread in case of any more questions.

Comment: I'm going to update some code to the question. I keep getting Object or With variable not set... Specifically, the code seems to stop at the last expression in the findRowB function I wrote.

Comment: Just saw your comment. I set the findRow to return the row number as an integer so I can reference it in cells later.

Comment: Sorry I kept deleting them, I was second guessing been a while since I did vba.

Comment: Haha It's okay. Right now, I'm also trying to figure out how to use the validation property for each cell. I am unable to do it with the cell so I have no idea how to select each range and use the validation property on it.